# How to catch checked status from a plugin while we are tweeking checked status outside plugin using a custom jQuery code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wrote some custom code in order to make a check box "checked". While I have a plugin which uses the checked status as written below:

```
this.checkboxContainer.find('input[type=checkbox]').click(function () {
    self.filter()
});
```

But as you can see it only works on click event. I tried this below but it looks like it does not do any thing.

```
this.checkboxContainer.find('input[type=checkbox]').filter()
```

Can any one please guide me.

Comment: What event would you prefer to use instead of `click`?

Comment: I just want I can run the function filter() which is inside a plugin when I checked the check box dynamically using other jQuery custom code

Comment: Is your function 'filter' called at all or is it the call to it that fails?

Comment: @Damp how to check it, but I think it does not call at all

Comment: @Imran, add a console.log statement in filter's function, you'll see in firebug/chrome console if the function is called

Comment: I checked it and its not calling at all